# Kernel menuconfig under Yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, config, yocto

I'm trying to configure a kernel in a Yocto build environment (bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig), and for some reason the new terminal that opens when running it simply runs a full compilation of the kernel and then exits, instead of simply opening the config menu.

This used to work with the same metas in the jethro branch, but now it doesn't with krogoth.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem, it appears that a custom implementation of the 'do_menuconfig' python function in the vendor meta layer (classes/*.bbclass), stuck around from an older version.

Simply removing that function and thus letting the default 'do_menuconfig' function run instead seemed to do the trick.